# Custom Cell Label

Tags: uitableview, swift

I have a custom cell that I'm designing.

[image]

I want to pass a string to that custom cell. I made a cocoa touch class called AlarmCell (subclass of UITableCell), and then called it with this code (in my UIViewController class):

```
let myCell = AlarmCell()
```

And then called the UILabel from within AlarmCell.

```
myCell.timeLabel?.text = newAlarm
```

newAlarm has the string "08:38 PM"

How come myCell.timelabel is coming out as nil? What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

AlarmCell Class:

```
class AlarmCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var timeLabel: UILabel!
}
```

Alarm(UIViewController Class):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { 
    let Cell  = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("alarmCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
```

I had:

```
cell.textLabel?.text = alarms[indexPath.row]
```

But I need to pass a string to a custom labl inside the cell

Comment: You can take screenshots with CMD + SHIFT + 3

Comment: Have you connected the outlets properly? Can we see a bit more code of the `AlarmCell` class and where the cell is loaded (`tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`)?

Comment: Is there a empty circle in font of IBOutlet or not?

Comment: No it's all connected. It doesn't crash, I just get nil

Comment: Can you post the full `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`'s body? I can't see why you have both `let Cell = tableView.deque...` and `let myCell = AlarmCell()`... Are they both in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do yourself a favor and create a **nib** file associated with your AlarmCell.swift class. After customizing the cell inside the nib file, declare the following inside your **viewDidLoad** function.

```
var nib = UINib(nibName: "AlarmCell", bundle: nil)
tableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

Then, mention it in your **cellForRowAtIndexPath** function as so:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell:AlarmCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as AlarmCell
    cell.timeLabel.text = alarms[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `cell.textLabel?.text = alarms[indexPath.row]` to

`Cell.timeLabel?.text = NSString(format: "%@", alarms[indexPath.row])`

And you should change the `let` keyword used for declaring the `Cell` object inside `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` method as follows:

```
var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("alarmCell") as UITableViewCell alarmCell
```

Answer (score 0):

Define Cell as

```
 var cell: AlarmCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("alarmCell") as UITableViewCell AlarmCell
```

then setTextLabel(or your Custom Label ) text as

```
 cell.textLabel?.text = alarms[indexPath.row] as NSString
```

comment below if any query as  this working perfectly for me